# Using Grunt and keeping theme comments

Tags: themes, css

I used Grunt to minify CSS then combine them together in my WordPress theme.   I combined all the CSS into 1 file called main.css .   However in order to register the theme I still need a style.css with theme comments.  The issue is Grunt gets rid of comments.  I would like to do achieve this in 1 http request vs 2.  I would like to have all my css in style.css right below the theme comments and get rid of main.css.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`style.css` may contain only comment with Theme Name: ... . It just tells to WordPress about your theme. You have no need to load style.css in theme through tag `<link ... >`.

So. Now you can leave your only one css file `main.css` with all styles in `<head>`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I just took out style.css from being loaded and my theme still works perfectly!  Such a simple solution.